# Exposing Azure Table with oData but working with "Domain" objects not Azure Entity Objects

Tags: azure, odata, iqueryable, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Pardon my terminology if incorrect but I'd rather not expose the Azure Table Entity objects directly to the end user, although I want to expose IQueryable.

How can I convert an `IQueryable<TableEntity>`  to `IQueryable<Object>`

I'm basing my oData logic as explained in this blog. Do share a better way if you have one.

http://blogs.southworks.net/fboerr/2010/07/29/create-a-wcf-data-service-odata-to-share-an-azure-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF Data Services can expose arbitrary objects using a [Reflection Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653.aspx). Instead of creating your classes by inheriting from TableServiceEntity you can create plain old C# classes with just the properties you like. In the query methods add a .Select() statement to create the POCO classes instead of the service classes.

You can also check [How to: Create a Data Service Using the Reflection Provider (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728281.aspx) for a step by step guide.

On the other hand, your TableServiceEntity doesn't have to match the underlying columns exactly. You can create entities with fewer columns and return these with a Select statement